# Stokes' theorem on intersection of $ x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Using Stokes' theorem, evaluate the line integral $$\int_L f\cdot dr $$ where $L$ is the intersection of $ x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y=0$ traversed in counter clockwise direction when viewed from $(1,1,0)$. $f=yi+zj+xk.$

I evaluated curl $f=-(î+j+k)$ and the normal vector to the plane $x+y=0$ is $ \frac{-(î+j)}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Since the curve lies in $x+y=0$ plane so I am having difficulty in further proceedings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal vector is $\frac{i+j}{\sqrt{2}}$, since the circle is traversed in counter clockwise direction.

Stoke's theorem then gives you $$\iint (-1,-1,-1)\cdot(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0) dS$$ where the surface is a circle with radius $1$. I think you can go from there.

Comment: Yes, but how did u see that after intersection its a circle of radius 1?

Comment: Because $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is a sphere with radius 1. The intersection is a circle on a disk that passes through the origin, the center of the sphere.

Comment: Oh yes thanks, btw which rule do u use to decide direction of normal vector?

Comment: Right hand rule.

Comment: Can u plz tell bcoz I always face problem when deciding direction of normal.

Comment: Use your right hand, curl your four fingers so that they point to the direction the curve goes, in this case, the counter clockwise direction of the circle, then your thumb points to the normal direction.

Comment: @ketan see http://mathinsight.org/stokes_theorem_orientation